# Ansible warns about template variables as part of string in 'when' condition

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following Ansible task, which is designed to run an nginx compile script if and only if the output of "nginx -v" does not match what is expected.

```
- name: get nginx version
  command: "{{ nginx_binary }} -v"
  register: result
  ignore_errors: True

- name: download and compile nginx
  include: install.yml
  when: result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version{{':'}} nginx/{{nginx_version}}"
```

When I run this with the latest version of Ansible, I get:

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. 
Found: result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version{{':'}}
nginx/{{nginx_version}}"
```

I'm confused about how to write this statement without the templating delimiters. If I remove the template variables around the colon character, I get:

```
- name: download and compile nginx
  include: install.yml
  when: result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version: nginx/{{nginx_version}}"
```

I get:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/Users/kevin/src/github.com/kevinburke/web-deployment/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml': line 13, column 58, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  include: install.yml
  when: result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version: nginx/{{nginx_version}}"
                                                         ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I also tried this but I still got a warning:

```
- name: download and compile nginx
  include: install.yml
  when: result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version: nginx/" + nginx_version
```

Any suggestions? It seems like if they are warning about this, there should be a way to write it that removes the warning, but I haven't found it so far.

Comment: I strongly doubt the warning is the same with your latest try. You should get a syntax error stating that `mapping values are not allowed in this context`. You need to quote the entire `when` value to fix it => `when: 'result.rc != 0 or result.stderr != "nginx version: nginx/" + nginx_version'`. Vladimir's answer below gives an even better way IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Put the strings into the variables, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: get nginx version
      command: nginx -v
      register: result
      ignore_errors: True

    - debug:
        var: result.stderr

    - name: 'download and compile nginx {{ nginx_version }}'
      debug:
        msg: "include: install.yml"
      when: result.stderr != _nginx_version
      vars:
        nginx_version: '1.18.0'
        _nginx_version: 'nginx version: nginx/{{ nginx_version }}'

    - name: 'download and compile nginx {{ nginx_version }}'
      debug:
        msg: "include: install.yml"
      when: result.stderr != _nginx_version
      vars:
        nginx_version: '1.18.1'
        _nginx_version: 'nginx version: nginx/{{ nginx_version }}'
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [srv] => 
  result.stderr: 'nginx version: nginx/1.18.0'

TASK [download and compile nginx 1.18.0] ***********************************
skipping: [srv]

TASK [download and compile nginx 1.18.1] ***********************************
ok: [srv] => 
  msg: 'include: install.yml'
```